# android xml not taking into account margins on custom layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

This is my custom view (**custom_view.xml**): ***Note that I define 3 margins on the CardView.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/left_image"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_image"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/right_image"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.ringapp.ui.view.TypefaceTextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <com.ringapp.ui.view.TypefaceTextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/right_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_md_gray_arrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I add the custom layout on the following xml (**container.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.ringapp.ui.view.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:description="edsc"
        app:title="title" />

    <com.ringapp.ui.view.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:description="asdasd"
        app:title="asdasdasd" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the margins that I defined on the custom_view.xml doesn't appear on the container.xml layout. Why is this happening? If I paste the code of custom_view.xml directly on container.xml the margins appears.

Comment: your container.xml has a customview with layout width and height as wrap_content. And what do you do in `com.ringapp.ui.view.CustomView` ?

Comment: try with padding

Comment: CustomView is extending CardView and I read the attributes that I set up.
Check the edit @Raghunandan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<com.ringapp.ui.view.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/test2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Try this:

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_view" android:id="@+id/test2/>
```

I believe when you use the code you have, android tries to over right some of your view's properties, especially when you explicitly overwrite the layout width / height. Try the above line of code in place of yours. Also, no need to overwrite the layout width / height if you're just going to wrap content, as the layout dimensions will be brought over from your custom_view.

Edit: To clarify, your code would probably even work if you took out the layout width / height overwrites. But you should use includes when bringing other XML layouts into a different XML layout. The way you 'included' your view is fine, but should probably be used fro when you write custom view classes that extend android 'View'.